# Struts2: How to insert the html result of an action inside the json result of another action

Tags: ajax, json, jsp, struts2

I have two actions. One is called `produceHtml.action`. The result is a rendered JSP page.
And the other action is called `produceJSON.action` which produces the jsonified content of an object.

Is it somehow possible to execute `produceHtml.action` inside `produceJSON.action` and put the resulting HTML into a string field of the object, so that it is part of the JSON result?

Comment: Why do you need this? If you need page return it if you need json use json.

Comment: The JSON result contains a couple of values that are needed to update a page and a block of HTML which is inserted somewhere in that page. I could just build this html block myself in code. But it would be a lot easier and nicer if I could have a regular JSP file and an action create it. That way I could use all the tags and struts functionality.
Right now I am doing it with two separate ajax calls. One get's the JSON and one retrieves the HTML block. But I would like to do it in only one call.

Comment: You can return jsp with some hidden values. So your html block will be returned from action and then you can retrieve hidden fields to update values that you're updating right now with json.

Comment: Yes that's actually my plan B. I might even hide the full JSON block inside the JSP. That would make it easier to parse and handle in the browser JS. But just for the heck of it, I am still wondering if it's possible to run down a full action and JSP dispatch to get the resulting HTML maybe as OutputStream. Instead of it being written to a HTTP response output stream.

Comment: You can use `stream` result. But it is not that simple if you want to process jsp also.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25936387/struts2-how-can-i-get-the-result-of-a-jsp-page-as-a-string-in-an-action-class), I found out that you can use the `RequestDispatcher` to process any arbitrary JSP. And a simple `HttpServletResponseWrapper` can be implemented to get the output as a string.

**Action**:

```
public class JsonAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletResponseAware, ServletRequestAware {

    public HttpServletResponse response;
    public HttpServletRequest request;
    private JsonResponse jsonResponse;
    private String jsp;

    @Override
    public void setServletResponse(HttpServletResponse hsr) {
        response = hsr;
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest hsr) {
        request = hsr;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        HttpServletResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new HttpServletResponseWrapper(response) {
            private final StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

            @Override
            public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
                return new PrintWriter(sw);
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return sw.toString();
            }
        };

        request.getRequestDispatcher(jsp).include(request, responseWrapper);

        jsonResponse = new JsonResponse();
        jsonResponse.val1 = "Hello World";
        jsonResponse.val2 = 42;
        jsonResponse.html = responseWrapper.toString();

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getJsp() {
        return jsp;
    }

    public void setJsp(String jsp) {
        this.jsp = jsp;
    }

    public JsonResponse getJsonResponse() {
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    public class JsonResponse {

        public String getVal1() {
            return val1;
        }

        public void setVal1(String val1) {
            this.val1 = val1;
        }

        public Integer getVal2() {
            return val2;
        }

        public void setVal2(Integer val2) {
            this.val2 = val2;
        }

        public String getHtml() {
            return html;
        }

        public void setHtml(String html) {
            this.html = html;
        }
        private String val1;
        private Integer val2;
        private String html;
    }
}
```

**struts.html Snippet**:

```
<package name="myapp" extends="json-default">

    <action name="jsonExample" class="JsonAction">
        <param name="jsp">/test.jsp</param>
        <result type="json">
            <param name="root">
                jsonResponse
            </param>
        </result>
    </action>

</package>
```

This will process `test.jsp` and puts the response into a string field of the `JsonResponse` object. Which is finally transmitted in JSON form.

The nice thing is, that the `ValueStack` at that point is fully initialized and has the `JsonAction` object on top of it. So it behaves like it would have been dispatched by the default struts dispatcher result.

BTW.: the example uses the [JSON Plugin](https://struts.apache.org/docs/json-plugin.html). Note the `extends="json-default"` in `struts.html`.